# How to get my class prediction LSTM Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I recently trying to build a program, that classify Quora (question pair) dataset, whether it's duplicate or not. I got the accuracy and loss based on real y, but IDK how to proceed the output (predicted y) can anyone help me?
the output shud be 1 or 0 (binary class)

This is the sentence merger code, training process use LSTM

```
merged = RNN(EMBED_HIDDEN_SIZE)(merged)

merged = layers.Dropout(dropoutp)(merged)
preds = layers.Dense(answer_size, activation='sigmoid')(merged)

model = Model([questiona, questionb], preds)

rmsprop = keras.optimizers.rmsprop(lr=lrn)
model.summary()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the predictions by passing the test data to predict funtion

```
predictions=model.predict(X)
```

[Link to the docs](https://keras.io/models/model/)

Comment: yeah thanks ^^ I got the output, but do you know, why the outputs are float number, isnt something like 1 or 0 ._.

Comment: Change the activation of the last layer to softmax